# Jquery Serialize with File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi this code isn't working. Im using this `serialize();` method but when I add an input type of file it isn't working. But if no file its working. Please help me.

```js
$("#resimBtn").on("click", function(){
    var dresim = $("#resimForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ayarlar/islem.php?islem=resim",
        type: 'POST',
        data: dresim ,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(cevap){
            $("#resimAlert").html(cevap).hide().fadeIn(700);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="resimForm" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" >

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Kategori Durum</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="file" name="resim">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div id="resimBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Ekle</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the data key inside the Ajax call function, use a form data.

```
var form = $('#resimForm')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
data: formData,
```

Alternatively you can use a submit handler.

```
$('#resimForm').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
//other Ajax stuff 
data: new FormData(this),
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

USE this:

```
var formData =  new FormData($('#resimForm')[0]);
$("#resimBtn").on("click", function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "ayarlar/islem.php?islem=resim",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData ,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(cevap){
                $("#resimAlert").html(cevap).hide().fadeIn(700);
            }
        });
    });
```